# How can I edit XML files on my HTC HD2 phone?

Tags: xml, editor

When I tap it, it opens with Opera. Is there something similar to the "Open With... Notepad" functionality we have in Windows OS? I can't seem to find any.

Also, Microsoft Word and Note mobile has no "Open file" function... That's why I can't edit it with these tools. I find it very odd.

If you guys know how, please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHP Notepad does the trick! http://www.freewarepocketpc.net/ppc-download-shp-notepad.html